# Cannot install apps on iOS 6.1.2; can't get through the account security questions

Tags: ios, applications

I bought an iPad with retina display yesterday, and this is my first iOS device.

After registering and connecting an Apple id, I tried to install some free apps.

But every time I press the `install app` button, there is a popup saying something like 'You need to setup three questions to improve the security level of your Apple id'(translated from Chinese).

I clicked the `continue` button, then there is a page to choose questions. But when I clicked to choose the first question, it jumps to a blank page and I never see any further response.

But when I clicked the `do it later`(translated from Chinese) button, it just quit installing the app.

**So neither way can I install an app.**

I also tried to reset iPad but it still does not work.

The fact is that I already fill the three questions&answers when updating to the current 6.1.2 version. I don't know why it asked me do that again.

What can I do to solve the problem?

**UPDATE:**

The problem magically disappeared this morning and I absolutely have no clue what the reason is.

Answer (score 1):

You should first try reseting the phone.

If that doesn't work, a few people had success in this [Apple discussion thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4266240?start=0&tstart=0) with signing into their account on a different phone that did not have the latest version of iOS on it.

So try signing into your account and setting your security questions from a friends phone. Then of course, remember to log off.

Comment: Resetting it doesn't work.

Comment: Try signing in from another persons device to your account and setting the security questions there.  If the first thing doesn't work, try the second right? :)

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem. Doing a reset fixed the problem.